# Read specific resource from classpath

Tags: java, classpath

I have a maven project and in class-path (`resources` folder according to maven standard layout) I have several `log4j.xml` files, like this:

```
-resources
    -log4j.xml
    -folder1
        -log4j.xml
    -folder2
        -log4j.xml
```

How I can read `log4j.xml` located at root? I think the following code doesn't guarantee that I will get `log4j.xml` from root:

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("log4j.xml")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless some other jar file is in the classpath of the current thread(s classloader, before yours, and also contains a log4j.xml file at the root, your code will do what you expect it to do.

To get the other one you would use `"folder1/log4j.xml"` as path.